# Spring Reactive WebSocket – serve from several Hot Streams

Tags: java, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor, spring-websocket

I'm using Spring WebFlux together with reactive WebSockets and trying to serve messages from
several Hot Fluxes. Here's how it looks:

```
      @Bean
      public WebSocketHandler webSocketHandler(MessageProducer<Message> messageProducer) {
        return session ->
        {
          Flux<Message> recentPosts = messageProducer.streamRecentPosts();

          Flux<Message> onLoadMorePosts = session.receive()
              .map(WebSocketMessage::getPayloadAsText)
              .map(this::toInputMessage)
              .filter(LoadMoreInputMessage.class::isInstance)
              .map(LoadMoreInputMessage.class::cast)
              .map(LoadMoreInputMessage::getLoaded)
              .flatMap(messageProducer::streamRecentPosts);

          Flux<Message> systemMessages = messageProducer.streamSystemMessages();
          Flux<Message> relevantSystemMessages = Flux.merge(recentPosts, onLoadMorePosts)
              .flatMap(post -> systemMessages
                  .filter(systemMessage -> systemMessage.getAffectedPostId() == null || post.getId().equals(systemMessage.getAffectedPostId()))
              );

          return session.send(recentPosts.map(this::stringify).map(session::textMessage))
              .and(session.send(onLoadMorePosts.map(this::stringify).map(session::textMessage)))
              .and(session.send(relevantSystemMessages.map(this::stringify).map(session::textMessage)));
        };
      }
```

Each Stream has its own Processor to push the data.
When the connection is established all the messages are served correctly but the issue is that the new messages are not emitted which defeats the purpose of WebSockets altogether. I found that the issue might be in `Flux.merge` but getting rid of it didn't seem to make any difference.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Why don't you just `subscribe` to the created `Flux` with a consumer sending the messages?

Comment: As I understand the WebSocket `session` is eventually subscribed to the created `Flux`.

Comment: The javadoc says "Note that merge is tailored to work with asynchronous sources or finite sources. When dealing with an infinite source that doesn't already publish on a dedicated Scheduler, you must isolate that source in its own Scheduler, as merge would otherwise attempt to drain it before subscribing to another source." Might be worth trying...